# Custom signals and multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, signals-slots

I've been trying to make this code work, but I still can't see where the flaw is.
I'm trying to emit the signal from a new thread, so the main receives the signal and executes a function.

If I try to do it within the same thread, everything works fine - but with this code, the thread is created, but the signal is never connected.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("From thread")
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("trying"))
        return

class Foo(QObject):            
    def handle_trigger(self):
        print ("trigger signal received")

    def new_thread(self):
        self.get_thread = WorkThread()
        self.connect(self.get_thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("trying"), self.handle_trigger)
        self.get_thread.start()


a = Foo()
a.new_thread()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited based on comments.

There is one main problem with your code. You're not actually starting the Qt application, so there is no main event loop running. You must add the following lines:

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

Also, you should use the [new-style Qt signals/slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) if possible, or if you stick with the old-style, know that the Qt Signal should be in the form of a C function if you want it to also [work with PySide](https://wiki.qt.io/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt#Old_style_signals_need_use_of_parentheses). To change this to work with PySide, it would be `QtCore.SIGNAL("trying()")`, not `QtCore.SIGNAL("trying")`. See the comments (specifically mine and @ekhumoro's comments) for details.

Here's a working version of your code (using the old-style signals/slots), I tried to change the least amount possible so that you could see the small changes. I had to use PySide instead, but it should work with PyQt as well:

```
from PySide.QtCore import * 
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide import QtCore
import sys

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("From thread")
        self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("trying()"))

class Foo(QObject):
    def handle_trigger(self):
        print ("trigger signal received")
        self.get_thread.quit()
        self.get_thread.wait()
        QApplication.quit()

    def new_thread(self):
        self.get_thread = WorkThread()
        self.connect(self.get_thread, QtCore.SIGNAL("trying()"), self.handle_trigger)
        self.get_thread.start()

a = Foo()
a.new_thread()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

And here's a version using the new signal/slot style (see @three_pineapples comment). This is the recommended way to implement signals/slots in PyQt/PySide.

```
from PySide.QtCore import * 
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide import QtCore
import sys

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
    ranThread = QtCore.Signal()
    # for PyQt, use QtCore.pyqtSignal() instead

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        print("From thread")
        self.ranThread.emit()

class Foo(QObject):
    def handle_trigger(self):
        print ("trigger signal received")
        self.get_thread.quit()
        self.get_thread.wait()
        QApplication.quit()

    def new_thread(self):
        self.get_thread = WorkThread()
        self.get_thread.ranThread.connect(self.handle_trigger)
        self.get_thread.start()

a = Foo()
a.new_thread()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
app.exec_()
```

Comment: To avoid such mistakes in the future, it is better to just switch to the new style of signals and slots. See the [PyQt documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) for more details.

Comment: Agreed on what @three_pineapples said. But it is wrong to say that old-style signal definitions must be in the form of a function. In fact, **any** string can be used for a custom signal - even an empty string! The only thing that matters is that the strings match (although not *exactly* - whitespace is ignored). The real error in the OPs example is that it doesn't run an event-loop - which is required for processing asynchronous, cross-thread signals, but not for synchronous, direct signals.

Comment: On my computer with PySide, leaving out the brackets causes a segmentation fault.

Comment: Just read that old-style signal defenition that are not in the C form are not supported on PySide, so it is best not to use them even on PyQt. See here: https://wiki.qt.io/Differences_Between_PySide_and_PyQt#Old_style_signals_need_use_of_parentheses

Comment: @Steve. I suppose I should have made it clear I was talking about the OPs original example, which is PyQt. But, anyway, this is all a bit moot now, since there is never any reason to use old-style signals in new code.

Comment: @ekhumoro. I agree, I updated the answer to mention that it's only required for PySide, and put more emphasis on the new-style signals/slots.

Comment: Thanks you very much. what does exactly @ekhumoro means when he said ' The real error in the OPs example is that it doesn't run an event-loop - which is required for processing asynchronous, cross-thread signals, but not for synchronous, direct signals '. Where can I read more about that

Comment: @GabrielGimenez. Try: [Signals and Slots Across Threads](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads) and [Threads, Events, QObjects](http://wiki.qt.io/ThreadsEventsQObjects#6c678d88cb4b92f3adbd4d6182d6ea78)

Answer (score 1):

I muddled through this myself and I think this will work for you.

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4 import QtCore

class WorkThread(QtCore.QThread):
 def __init__(self):
  QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

 tryThis =    QtCore.Signal(str)   #added this variable

 def run(self):
  print("From thread")
  x = "trying"
  self.tryThis.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL(x))  #pass your new variable like this
  return

class Foo(QObject):

    def handle_trigger(self):
        print ("trigger signal received")

    def new_thread(self):
        self.get_thread = WorkThread()        
        self.get_thread.start()
        self.get_thread.tryThis.connect(self.handle_trigger,QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)  #passed it here

a = Foo()
a.new_thread()
```